# Looking for smooth handled bar spoon w/ muddler

Tags: bartending

Looking for a very specific bar spoon (image included).

[image]It is smooth-handled (important), with a muddler, 11 inches long. Has a nice weight to it. Anyone seen this before?

I saw a similar one here ( https://cocktailreligion.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/bar-kit/ ), but the blog is inactive.

Thanks for any leads on where to get one!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want specifically this bar spoon? Both smooth handles and muddlers are less common on barspoons. Both on a single spoon is, I think, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this source](https://www.socialhourcocktails.com/barpsoons) on the internet - which will then take you to all sorts of sites that have what you are looking for - good luck!

EDIT:  I believe [this](http://eu.cocktailkingdom.com/?___store=eu_en&UseLoc=ES) is what you want.  It also has a thermometer!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thermometer spoon suggestion- although it's not the same spoon. The one in the photograph is one solid piece of stainless steel, and does not include a thermometer.